# How to simulate a tree growth while changing its height with a slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular

I am trying to understand how binding values work in angular.js. I am truly a beginner. I wonder how you can make a tree grow as you moove up a slider and how it can shrink as you moove it down. I will work on it to make it nice and beautiful after, I just want to understand the basics to help me moove forward.

What I am trying to do first, is to make a branch that split into two small branches when it hits 50px high. 
The height should be equal to the value of a slider that goes from 0 to 100
The thickness of a branch at x would be 0.1*(100-x), that way the origin is thincker that the end and it thickens as it grows. 
If x=0 then nothing is visible
Else If x<50 then a branch of x pixels high is drawn upfrom bottom middle of the canvas
Else you have a branch of 50 pixels height and two branches going from the end of the first branch to (x-50) height, at 30° and -30° angle.

I tried by playing with html div (each branch was a div) but it was ugly and I don't see how to add the thickness part (beacause at the end I would like something nice). I tried also to modify this http://jsfiddle.net/GertG/gv2z9r72/show but I couldn't find my way in this as I don't know anything about jQuery.

I should say that being able to go back as it was when sliding down, really matters.

If you know things to make it more nice (curvy for exemple) that would really help me for the next steps !

```
<p><canvas class="tree" width="800" height="600" /></p>
<input id="sizeTree" type="range" min="0" max="150" />
```

```
#sizeTree {
    width:600px;
}
```

```
(function() {

    var sizeTree = 0;
    var thickness;
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    canvas = $('canvas.tree')[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var ox = canvas.width / 2,
    var oy = canvas.height - 40

    if (sizeTree=0) {
        // nothing visible in the canvas
    } else {
    //draw branch of min(sizeTree,50) length with the right thickness (at y should be equal to 0.1*(100-y)) from (ox,oy) to (ox,oy+sizeTree)
        if (sizeTree>50) {
            //draw 2 branches at -30° and 30° from 50 to sizeTree

            // For the first one from (ox,oy+50) to (ox+(tan(30°)*sizeTree-50), oy+sizeTree)
            // For the second one from (ox,oy+50) to (ox-(tan(30°)*sizeTree-50), oy+sizeTree)
        }
    }   

}());
```

I do not expect it to be pretty but I want something that can be turned into something prettier. If I need to had libraries just let me know, i would like it to be compatible with angular.js as I would like to add it to an old project first. If you think of another way to do it with Angular, just let me know, but that is not my first concern. For the parcimony principle, I would like to avoid adding multiple libraries if it is doable with less ;)

Thank you very much for you help !